# Real valued continuous function on a closed disc

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Assume that $D\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ is a closed disc and $S$ is its boundary circle. Moreover $x,y\in S$ are distinct points, which determine exactly two arcs $I,J\subseteq S$, and $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a continuous function such that $f(x)<0$, $f(y)>0$.

I want to prove the following:

There exist points $p\in I$, $q\in J$ and a connected set $C\subseteq f^{-1}(0)$ such that $p,q\in C$.

To me it seems intuitively true, but I have no serious idea how to prove it. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I see no reason to think that $f$ vanishes on a nontrivial arc $C$.

Comment: OK, I understand.  Perhaps this is asserting that the disk is "two-dimensional" in the sense of large inductive dimension.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_dimension

Comment: @GEdgar, it is just a disc on the plane $\mathbb R^2$. I made it clear in the edit now.

Comment: By connectivity of $I$ and $J$ it's certainly true that points $p,q$ exist in $I,J$ at which $f$ vanishes. I can only assume we need to find a path from $p\to q$ along which $f$ vanishes but this seems to hard to show the existence of

Comment: @FShrike Such a *path* connecting these two points need not exist. You ought to allow more general connected subsets.

Comment: @Wojowu I allow it, but intuitively reasoning about the problem suggested to me that the solution may involve constructing a path.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea for a construction:

This reminds me of the game hex https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_(board_game)
and the proof that there is always a winner.

There does not seem to be anything special about the structure of the disk in your problem, so we could think of it as a hex board, with $x$ and $y$ being on opposite sides. Further assume:

1. $f$ is negative on every hexagon on the left side
2. $f$ is positive on every hexagon on the right side

If $f$ is has a zero on a hexagon, mark it red, otherwise blue.

If there were a path of blue hexagons from left to right, we would have a contradiction by the intermediate value theorem. So there must be a path of red hexagons from top to bottom.

Of course this does not give a continuous path, but I suspect that by refining the grid, we could construct a path (or at least a connected set) in the limit.

Comment: This idea looks very vague to me. What kind of limit is it?

Comment: My thought was a limit similar to how one constructs a space-filling curve https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve. Connect the zeros in the initial hex path to form a curve. Then refine. However, I completely agree that this is vague. I have not fleshed it out to confirm the details.

Answer (score 1):

**Strategy:** I'll do a proof by contradiction, assuming that $f^{-1}(0)$ has no connected component $\Gamma$ that intersect's $I$ and $J$. In this setting i'll construct a continuous curve that connect two points $P_1,P_2$ s.t. $f(P_1)>0, f(P_2)<0$ and the contradiction will follows by the [Intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

**Setting:** The decomposition in connected components of $f^{-1}(0)$ is:
$$ f^{-1}(0)=\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha    \cup\bigcup_\beta B_\beta   \cup\bigcup_\gamma C_\gamma,\;\;  \text{ where: } $$ $$A_\alpha\cap I\neq \emptyset,\;\;  B_\beta\cap J\neq \emptyset,\;\;C_\gamma\cap I=C_\gamma\cap J= \emptyset,  $$ Lets define $A=\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha,\;\; B=\bigcup_\beta B_\beta$.
[image]

Because i want work with the open set of $\mathbb R^2$, lets call $x',y'$ two point  inside in disc near to $x$ and $y$ s.t. $f(x')>0,f(y')<0.$

**$A$ enlargement:** In this part I want expand $A$ to have a nicer boundary that will be useful in the next part, in the same time i want to preserve some of his property (does not intersect $x,x',y,y',I,B,C$ and the compactness ).
$$\varepsilon:=\frac{1}{3}\min \{d(A,x),d(A,x'),d(A,y),d(A,y'),d(A,I),d(A,B),d(A,C)\}, $$ and now I extract a finite open covering from the trivial covering with the $\varepsilon-$balls: $$A\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^N B(k_i,\varepsilon)\subset \overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^N B(k_i,\varepsilon)}   =A_\varepsilon. $$

[image]

**Study of set $D\backslash A_\varepsilon$:** Now we'r studying topological property of the connected component of $\stackrel{\circ}{D}\backslash A_\varepsilon$ that contains $x'$, lets call $X$ that open set. Because $A_\varepsilon$ its compact  that doesn't intersect the compact $I$, there is a distance $d>0$ between this two disjoint set, so we can construct a path $\gamma$ (near to $I$, inside $X$) that link  the two points $x',y'\implies y'\in X$.

Now observes that $X^c\subset \mathbb R^2$ (its only the union of $D^c,S^1,A$ and the other connected component of $\stackrel{\circ}{D}\backslash A$ that have the boundaries in $A_\varepsilon\cup S^1 $) its  connected, and by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2712861/open-and-connected-subset-in-mathbbr2) we get that $X$ is simply connected (we used the fact that $S^1\cap A_\varepsilon\neq \emptyset$). So $X\subset \mathbb R^2$ is a non-empty, open subset of $\mathbb R^2$, simply-connected, hence by the [Riemann mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem) its biholomorphic to the open unit disc:
$$\phi:X\to \stackrel{\circ}{D}.$$
Now by construction, the $X$'s  boundary is regular enough (remember that $X$ is one component of $\stackrel{\circ}{D}\backslash \{\text{finite balls}\}$) to satisfy the $3.$ property of  [Cecchi's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3416210/riemann-mapping-theorem-continuously-extending-to-boundary/3416851#3416851), hence we can extend $\phi$ to the closure (and it is still an homeomorphism): $$\phi:\overline X\to D $$

**Study of set $X\backslash B$:** Now $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$ goes to the boundary and define two arc (like before) $I',J'$ and by continuity (wlog) $\phi(I)=I'$.
$\phi(B)$ is compact and intersect $I'$ and its disjoint from $J'$ so there exists (like before) a path $\gamma'(t)$ near to $J'$ that links $\phi(x)$ to $\phi(y)$ disjoint from $\phi(B)$, more we can request that $\gamma'(t)$ is disjoint from $\phi(C)$ (it is compact and disjoint from $J'$ too). Finally we get a path $\gamma(t)=\phi^{-1}\circ\gamma'(t)$ in $X$ disjoint from $B$ and $C$, hence a path in $D$ disjoint from $A$,$B$ and $C$ that links $x$ to $y$.

**Contradiction :** Now we get a contradiction because $f\circ \phi(t)$ is never zero (the support of $\phi$ doesn't intersect $f^{-1}(0)=A\cup B\cup C$) and is a continuous map that start positive and ends negative.

Comment: This looks great. Can you be sure there is a path $x’\to y’$ inside $X$? It seems to me you should cover $A$ by epsilon balls *first* and then there will be a positive distance from $I$ and then there will exist $x’$, $y’$ sufficiently close to $x$ and $y$ with which you can make a path. But if you fix $x’,y’$ first, I’m not so sure

Comment: Maybe I should fix two open ball's $B_1,B_2$ such that they contain respectively $x$ and $y$ and $f(B_1)>0, f(B_2)<0$ (x',y' are some random points in these balls). Now i can define $\varepsilon$ such that its smaller than $d(B_i,A)$. Now from $x'$ i can go safely to $x$ (with a curve inside $B_1$) and from $x$ than i can use a curve near to $I$... what do you think?

Comment: I think that works. I'd just use a curve along the arc $I$ itself, to be safe

Comment: I cannot use that curve because i'm working with one component of $\stackrel{\circ}{D}\backslash A$ that does't contain $I$ itself. In the proof I exploits the fact that $d(A,I)>\varepsilon$ so if i take a curve  $\gamma\subset \stackrel{\circ}{D}$ such that $d(\gamma(t),I)<\varepsilon/2$ I'm sure that $\gamma $ does't intersect $A$ .